# How to replace the door lock relay on Honda CRV 2005

Tags: honda, locks, door, relay, crv

I have a Honda CRV 2005 with the driver door power lock not working.

Here are the symptoms:

1. Power lock driver side doesn't work, but all other doors work fine,
2. I can lock and unlock the driver door manually with the key,
3. but can't unluck it either with the door switch or the keyless button,
4. If I power lock the car with the key (or the driver switch), all doors lock but the driver's door.
5. Everytime I do so, I hear a clicking noise in the fuse panel under the driving wheel.

I have check online and found that most of the time, it's the actuator that is faulty.  I've then bought a new one, replaced it, but it didn't help.  I've then tested both my old and new actuator on an other door and they both work find.  **So my problem isn't the actuator**.  More search online led to a door lock relay problem.  I would like to test that, but I can't find anywhere information on are to change it and what part is necessary.

I've found the fuse and relay diagram online (http://fusesdiagram.com/honda/fuses-and-relay-honda-cr-v-2002-2006.html) but can figure what relay controls the door locks.

So the summary of my question:

1. Where is the door lock relay on a Honda CRV 2005?
2. How do I replace it and what part is needed?
3. Will I have to reprogram my keys after doing so and if yes, is it easy?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to this Stack! Great first question :o)

Comment: I acquired a full wiring diagram from Honda. Text your email address in the next comment.

Comment: Hi - did you ever solve this problem?  I have the identical symptoms on an 05 CR-V that I just bought.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The door lock/unlock relays are built into the multiplex unit on that year CR-V and are not serviceable (See Figs. 1 & 2). To replace it you'd either have to replace the whole multiplex unit or crack it open, trace out the board and solder in a new relay.

To test the relay you would have to gain access to the back of the multiplex unit connector M (22 in Fig 2). On a lock command the driver door lock relay powers terminal 9 and there should be a ground on terminal 7. And the other way around on an unlock command.

Since you already replaced the driver door lock actuator I'd suggest you take a look at the wiring. A common failure point is in the rubber sleeve that goes from the interior to the door.

Fig 1.
[image: Fig 1]

Fig 2.

> Socket    Ref     Terminal    Connects to
>
> A     2   5   Dashboard wire harness B (see DASHBOARD WIRE HARNESS B )
> B  3   6   Dashboard wire harness B (see DASHBOARD WIRE HARNESS B )
> C  1   14  Dashboard wire harness B (see DASHBOARD WIRE HARNESS B )
> D  4   12  ECM/PCM wire harness (see ECM/PCM WIRE HARNESS )
> E  5   13  ECM/PCM wire harness (see ECM/PCM WIRE HARNESS )
> F  19  12  Engine compartment wire harness (see ENGINE COMPARTMENT WIRE HARNESS (DASH BRANCH) )
> G  9   10  Engine compartment wire harness (see ENGINE COMPARTMENT WIRE HARNESS (DASH BRANCH) )
> H  8   3   Engine compartment wire harness (see ENGINE COMPARTMENT WIRE HARNESS (DASH BRANCH) )
> I  20  5   Engine compartment wire harness (see ENGINE COMPARTMENT WIRE HARNESS (DASH BRANCH) )
> J  21  8   Engine compartment wire harness (see ENGINE COMPARTMENT WIRE HARNESS (DASH BRANCH) )
> K  23  17  Dashboard wire harness A (see DASHBOARD WIRE HARNESS A (LEFT BRANCH) )
> L  24  10 Dashboard wire harness A (see DASHBOARD WIRE HARNESS A (LEFT BRANCH) )
> M  22  12  Dashboard wire harness A (see DASHBOARD WIRE HARNESS A (LEFT BRANCH) )
> N  27  6   Dashboard wire harness A (see DASHBOARD WIRE HARNESS A (LEFT BRANCH) )
> O  26  12  Dashboard wire harness A (see DASHBOARD WIRE HARNESS A (LEFT BRANCH) )
> P  7   18  ECM/PCM wire harness (see ECM/PCM WIRE HARNESS )
> Q  6   8   ECM/PCM wire harness (see ECM/PCM WIRE HARNESS )
> R  10  6   ECM/PCM wire harness (see ECM/PCM WIRE HARNESS )
> Power window relay     12  4
> S  25  2 ECM/PCM wire harness (see ECM/PCM WIRE HARNESS )
> Starter cut relay 14   4
> T  18  3   Multiplex control inspection connector
> Taillight relay    13  4
> Turn signal/hazard relay   11  3
> U  15  1   Optional connector
> V  16  4   Optional connector
> W (Memory erase signal (MES) connector)    17  2   ECM/PCM wire harness (see ECM/PCM WIRE HARNESS )
> X  28  8   (Plugs directly into the multiplex control unit)
> Y  29  13  (Plugs directly into the multiplex control unit)

[image: Fig 2]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The relay not being serviceable would explain why there is so few info about it online...  I've found that (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-TG8NYXjqgk) which pretty much explains the wiring problem.  I wasn't confident of fixing my problem that way but I'll give it a shot.  As for fixing or replacing the multiplex, I don't think it worths the trouble on a 12 years old car...

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem it ended up being the connector on the motor